# Puppet/Augeas -- ins command worked on RH6, fails on RH7

Tags: redhat, puppet, augeas

I have this construct in my puppet module to add a line in `/etc/sudoers` after the last "Defaults" line:

```
  augeas { "sudoers.ssh_auth_sock" :
    lens => "Sudoers.lns",
    incl => "/etc/sudoers",
    onlyif  => "match Defaults/env_keep/var[. = 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK'] size==0",
    changes => [
       # Create a new Defaults line for the two variables
       "ins Defaults after Defaults[last()]",
       # Make this Defaults line a += type
       "clear Defaults[last()]/env_keep/append",
       # assign values to the two variables
       "set Defaults[last()]/env_keep/var[1] SSH_AUTH_SOCK",
    ],
  }
```

It works perfectly on my RedHat 6 machines

```
Notice: Augeas[sudoers.ssh_auth_sock](provider=augeas):
--- /etc/sudoers        2021-10-12 13:30:52.880901115 +0000
+++ /etc/sudoers.augnew 2021-10-12 13:31:28.697931561 +0000
@@ -77,6 +77,7 @@
 # Defaults   env_keep += "HOME"

 Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
+Defaults env_keep += SSH_AUTH_SOCK

 ## Next comes the main part: which users can run what software on

Notice: /Stage[main]/Sudoers/Augeas[sudoers.ssh_auth_sock]/returns: executed successfully
```

But it fails on my RedHat 7 machines:

```
Warning: Augeas[sudoers.ssh_auth_sock](provider=augeas): Loading failed for one or more files, see debug for /augeas//error output
Error: /Stage[main]/Sudoers/Augeas[sudoers.ssh_auth_sock]: Could not evaluate: Error sending command 'ins' with params ["Defaults", "after", "/files/etc/sudoers/Defaults[last()]"]/Error sending command 'ins' with params ["Defaults", "after", "/files/etc/sudoers/Defaults[last()]"]
```

Can somebody help me understand what changed, or what I did wrong, so that I can get this snippet to work in both environments?

Comment: `loading failed` in the logs is a hint that Augeas couldn't parse one or more files. Can you run `augtool errors` and post the output?

Comment: Thank you @raphink -- problem resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @raphink

`augtool errors` said

```
Error in /etc/sudoers:96.12 (parse_failed)
  Iterated lens matched less than it should
  Lens: /usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/sudoers.aug:530.10-.70:
    Last matched: /usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/sep.aug:47.18-.40:
    Next (no match): /usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/sudoers.aug:500.16-501.47:
```

So I checked line 96 of `/etc/sudoers` and it said

```
@includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Apparently, `@includedir` is now a valid syntax in addition to the older-style syntax `#includedir` ... but (my) augeas lens does not recognize the new version.

```
(* View: includedir *)
let includedir =
  [ key /#include(dir)?/ . Sep.space . store Rx.fspath . eol ]
```

I changed the `@` to a `#` in `/etc/sudoers` and that seems to have resolved the problem.

Comment: Great. If the latest Augeas doesn't support this syntax, please open an issue (or even better provide a PR to fix it).